# Android - Upload video/audio file to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Storage to save video/audio user's files.
My main idea is to save each video/audio under user ID (UID).
It means to each user has several videos/audios files savedd under his UID.
I worte a code that the problem is that he keep saving the new video on the old video that i have saved.
Please tell me where i'm wrong

```
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST) {
            Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
            String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            videoRef = storageRef.child("/videos/" + userUid );
            //TODO: save the video in the db
            uploadData(selectedVideoUri);
        }else if(requestCode == PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST){
            //TODO: save the audio in the db
        }
    }
}

private void uploadData(Uri videoUri) {
    if(videoUri != null){
        UploadTask uploadTask = videoRef.putFile(videoUri);

        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBarUpload.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                updateProgress(taskSnapshot);
            }
        });
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Nothing to upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the same file path *every* time for that user's uploads:

```
videoRef = storageRef.child("/videos/" + userUid);
```

Instead, you'll need to come up with some unique file name for each upload, and treat the user id as a directory component rather than the name of the file itself:

```
String filename = "you put a unique file name here";
videoRef = storageRef.child("/videos/" + userUid + "/" + filename);
```

Comment: to add image , video and record video on same layout how to do

Answer (score 0):

**You can use current time to make unique id like this**

```
    StorageReference videoRef =storageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+userUid+);
```

By doing this you will get every time a unique id to save your file . 
This works for me