# data is not saving in firebase database java android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am downloading and uploading the name and URL of audios from firebase storage.
I downloaded the URL and name successfully but this is not uploading to the firebase database

> data downloading and uploading

```
StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("Ringtone");
        reference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(listResult -> {
            Log.d("Tag","reference listed");
            for(StorageReference item:listResult.getItems()){

                Task<Uri> downloadUrlTask = item.getDownloadUrl();
                Task<StorageMetadata> downloadNameTask = item.getMetadata();

                Tasks.whenAll(downloadNameTask,downloadUrlTask).addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {

                    Methods methods = new Methods();
                    methods.firebse_ring_upload(downloadNameTask.getResult().getName(),downloadUrlTask.getResult());
                });
            }
        });
```

> Method class

```
package com.example.alarm.Methods;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.alarm.Models.RingtoneModel;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Methods {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    public void firebse_ring_upload(String songName, Uri uri){
        RingtoneModel ringtoneModel = new RingtoneModel(songName,uri.toString());
        database.getReference().child("Ringtones_Room").child(songName.replace(" ","").replaceAll("[\\W+]","")).setValue(ringtoneModel);

    }

}
```

> RingtoneModel (POJO class)

package com.example.alarm.Models;

```
import android.net.Uri;

public class RingtoneModel {
    String SongName;
    String uri;

    public RingtoneModel(String songName, String uri) {
        SongName = songName;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public RingtoneModel(){}

    public String getSongName() {
        return SongName;
    }

    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        SongName = songName;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri.toString();
    }
}
```

previously this was showing `StackOverflow error` because I was trying to save URI in the database. but this should work now. This not showing me any type of error also.

if any other info required. comment down

> **Edit**

I updated my method just like this: (`in method class`)

```
public void firebse_ring_upload(String songName, Uri uri){
        RingtoneModel ringtoneModel = new RingtoneModel(songName,uri.toString());
        database.getReference("https://alarm-sachinbudak-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/").child("Ringtones_Room").child(songName.replaceAll("[\\W+]","")).setValue(ringtoneModel);

    }
```

but this is giving me a new error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: https://alarm-sachinbudak-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validatePathString(Validation.java:45)
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateRootPathString(Validation.java:58)
            at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(FirebaseDatabase.java:181)
            at com.example.alarm.Methods.Methods.firebse_ring_upload(Methods.java:14)
            at com.example.alarm.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$3(MainActivity.java:85)
```

[image: my firebase database screenshot]

Comment: do you have write permissions enabled for the collection

Comment: @ O-9 my write permission is enabled

Comment: try this https://medium.com/@winision/firebase-storage-to-upload-pdf-docx-audio-and-video-using-kotlin-8a1691bbe116  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47538218/12709358

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens if the Task is not successful? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Also: where is your Firebase Realtime Database hosted? If it's not in the US (the default region), you might want to pass its URL to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(urlToDatabaseHere)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my location is singapur

Comment: In that case, please check the duplicate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please check my question again. (Edited)

Comment: @AlexMamo Please check my question again. (Edited)

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the duplicate answer?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks, Alex! I completely wasted 2 days. You saved 1 day.

Comment: Good to hear that you solved it. You're very welcome, Sachin!